# What are the AllowOverride settings if you're hosted on GoDaddy?

Tags: apache, htaccess

I'm looking for the `AllowOverride` setting for GoDaddy hosting, does anybody know where I can find that?

Answer (score 1):

it should be available editing an .htaccess file on any folder starting on the web-root.